# Jmeter Test run locally and generated report however remotely does not stop

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, distributed-testing

I have Jmeter Test which is launched from the Master Machine(Win 10) to be run on a slave virtual machine (Ubuntu),  when I run the test locally (Win10) it take few minutes and it finished successfully with an html report, but running it on the Remote Machine (Ubuntu virtual) it finshed too (i can see it in the slave machine), but on the master (Win 10) the non gui jmeter command still running and does not stop, an no html report or jtl file is generated.

1. Java version on master & slave -openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
2. Java version on slave -openjdk "11.0.7" 2020-01-14
3. Jmeter Version: 5.2.1 (both master & slave)
4. VirtualBox: 6.0
5. VirtualMachine:Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan Ermine

here on the slave machine showing me the test is over:

[image]

and here on the master ,the non gui jmeter command still running and does not stop:

[image]

Comment: my problem was  when I started the <jmeter-server.bat> file, which does not point to the Host IP address (Master), but to another IP which has been added by Docker Desktop...to solve it, I commented the IP adress added by the docker on the file hosts in < C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts>, then it works..

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out *jmeter-server.log* file on the slave, it should contain error details if something is wrong with your setup
2. Make sure to use [bridged adapter](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) to the slave would have its own IP address and act like a "real" machine with independent network configuration
3. Double check [RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) for the master and the slave, it might be the case the slave is not capable of connecting to the master in order to transfer the test results
4. According to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)